# I want to send Email Behalf of other in android project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gmail-api, google-account

```
      I am developing App In android Kotlin I serach alot can anyone can help me to solve this
```

I want User athenticate his email in my app and i access his Account and when he allow me to send email from my app
the permission is send email behalf of other i see in many apps i dont know how to do that i intergate Gmail Api but didnot scussfully done it because if i do code the error in packege that i used  these
`

```
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:19.2.0'
   implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.34.1'
   implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
   implementation'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev82-1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.11.0'`  


`               val credentials = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                  applicationContext, Collections.singleton(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SETTINGS_BASIC)
              )

               val service = Gmail.Builder(
                   AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), GsonFactory(), credentials
               ).setApplicationName("YourAppName").build()

               val sendAs = SendAs().apply {
                    sendAsEmail = "sendasemail@example.com"

                }

                val request = service.users().settings().sendAs().create("me", sendAs)
                    val response = request.execute()`
```

is their Any one who can solve this issue